# Insert if no PK violation

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a routine that regularly checks a database and make changes if necessary.

Let me explain my problem with the following example.
A Database stores participants and winners of tournaments.

We got two tables storing the base data (tournaments, people)
Furthermore we got two more tables for the references.

1. Winner table that store tournamentId and peopleId
2. Participant table that stores tournamentId and peopleId

Now the script should take every entry from the winner table and insert it into the participant table because every winner is a participant as well.

```
Insert Into ParticipantTable 
Select * From WinnerTable
```

However some users of the database insert winners in the participant table manually, some don't.
The code above won't work since PK Violations can appear.

How can I tell the statement to make insertion only if the entry isn't in participant table yet?

Thanks in advance, sorry for my messi english and keep in mind that the example above is fictional I am aware that the described data model doesn't fit perfectly for the described usecase.

Comment: Have you considered `NOT EXISTS` or a `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

```
merge ParticipantTable as trg
    using WinnerTable as src on src.pk_col1 = trg.pk_col1
                                and src.pk_col2 = trg.pk_col2
                                ... /* here is PK columns binding */
when not matched then
    insert  (col1, col2, col3, ...)
    values (src.col1, src.col2, src.col3, ...);
```